# how many database tables is too much?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a project for a school and so far I have 91 tables on a single database. All tables are linked with each other.

Is it normal to have this many tables in one database?

**OR**

Do i need to make multiple databases?

If I do make multiple databases how can I link them together?

Comment: This question would be much more useful if you gave an example - apart from the student table, the existence of which tables made you worry?

Comment: 91? Try 800. Depending what you do, 91 does not even cut the main tables in an application. SAP R3 has more than 10000 tables, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a few years, I contracted with large firms to come in and fix up databases in sad need of repair.  The databases were broken in a variety of ways.
100 tables strikes me as the middle of the range.  They ranged from a low of about 30 tables to a high of over 500 tables.

This was in a previous century, so things may have changed.

One thing that has certainly changed is databases embedded in a single application.  Designing and building databases was so difficult that they just about had to be multipurpose to justify the effort and expense,

Answer (score 2):

10K tables can be a performance problem -- Tables are implemented using OS files, and the OS gets sluggish with that many files (etc) in a directory.

91 smells like "over normalization".  Do not normalize "continuous" values likes dates and floats.  Doing so, leads to terrible performance whenever you need a 'range' query.

*Usually* it is wrong to have two tables with the same set of fields.  Hence, it is probably wrong to have different tables for different departments.  Ditto for "forms".

*Usually* it is wrong to have two tables in a 1:1 mapping.  So "most of the tables are linked to the student and the teacher" worries me.

Comment: the forms are different in a sense that they have different kind of information and fields, and the linking is not 1:1 it's 1:m like I have a attendance table which is linked with the student, each student would have different attendance.